# Nest.js app becomes unresponsive following an Error thrown in an async function without an await

Tags: nestjs

The issue that if there is an exception thrown in an `async` function but that function was called without an `await`, the Nest application goes into a state where it no longer responds to requests but the process does not exist.

There may be times where we want to call a function in a request but don't need to wait for it to finish before returning to response to the caller but most of the time that we encounter this it was just an accidental omission of an `await`. The fact that it renders the server useless has been very problematic.

I suspect there may be a simple solution to this problem but I have been unsuccessful in finding it myself.

app.controller.ts

```js
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }

  @Get('/crash')
  public async crash(): Promise<void> {
    await this.appService.crash();
  }
}
```

app.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

const sleep = async (ms: number): Promise<void> => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
};

const functionThatThrows = async (): Promise<void> => {
  await sleep(2000);
  throw new Error('this will crash the app');
};

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  getHello(): string {
    return 'Hello World!';
  }

  public async crash(): Promise<void> {
    console.log('crashing the app in 3 seconds...');
    await sleep(1000);
    functionThatThrows(); // async function called without await
  }
}
```

Calling the endpoint the first time succeeds:

`curl http://localhost:3000/crash`

Calling it afterward and the server does not respond:

`curl http://localhost:3000/crash`

`curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000 after 5 ms: Connection refused`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is due to the fact that **node** crashes on unhandled promise rejections. Nest's exception filter will catch errors that happen **during** the request, but if an error happens outside of the request (like a promise/async function without an `await`), then only the standard Node error handler is active. You'd need a `process.on('unhandledRejection', errorHandler)` to keep the process from crashing

Comment: They have to add a try catch block somewhere most preferably in the service

Comment: @Craques actually because the promise is not `await`ed they have to use `.catch` on the promise